# Type 'Query<TerritoryDoc[], TerritoryDoc>' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I am using Mongoose for my development and I have a Territory Model as below.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { UserDoc, AgencyDoc } from '@ssomlk-org/distribution-common';
import { AreaDoc } from './Area';

// An interface that describes the properties
// that are required to create a new Territory
interface TerritoryAttrs {
  area: string;
  agency: string;
  code: string;
  description: string;
  createdBy: string;
}

// An interface the describes the properties
// that a Territory model has
interface TerritoryModel extends mongoose.Model<TerritoryDoc> {
  build(attrs: TerritoryAttrs): TerritoryDoc;
}

// An interface that descripbe the properties
// that a Territory document has
interface TerritoryDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  area: AreaDoc;
  agency: AgencyDoc;
  code: string;
  description: string;
  status: string;
  createdBy: UserDoc;
  createdAt: string;
  modifiedAt: string;
}

const TerritorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    area: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Area',
      required: true,
    },
    agency: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Agency',
      required: true,
    },
    code: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      uppercase: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Active', 'Inactive'],
      default: 'Active',
      required: false,
    },
    createdBy: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: false,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    modifiedAt: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: {
      transform(doc, ret) {
        ret.id = ret._id;
        delete ret._id;
        delete ret.__v;
      },
    },
  }
);

TerritorySchema.index({ '$**': 'text' });

TerritorySchema.pre('save', async function (done) {
  this.set('modifiedAt', new Date().toISOString());
  if (this.isNew) {
    this.set('createdAt', new Date().toISOString());
    this.set('modifiedAt', undefined);
  }
  done();
});

TerritorySchema.statics.build = (attrs: TerritoryAttrs) => {
  return new Territory(attrs);
};

const Territory = mongoose.model<TerritoryDoc, TerritoryModel>(
  'Territory',
  TerritorySchema
);

export { Territory, TerritoryDoc };
```

I have a REST API to get territories as shown below

```
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { Document, DocumentQuery } from 'mongoose';
import {
  ApiFeatures,
  currentUser,
  requireAuth,
} from '@ssomlk-org/distribution-common';

import { Territory, TerritoryDoc } from '../../models/Territory';

const router = express.Router();

router.get(
  '/api/territories',
  currentUser,
  requireAuth,
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    let resourceCount = 0;
    const accessRoles = ['developer', 'admin'];
    const role = req.currentUser!.role;

    /************** GET RESOURCE TOTAL COUNT START **************/
    let queryTotal: DocumentQuery<Document[], Document> = Territory.find({});

    if (!accessRoles.includes(role)) {
      queryTotal = queryTotal.where('agency').equals(req.currentUser!.agency);
    }

    const countTotalFeatures = new ApiFeatures(queryTotal, req.query)
      .filter()
      .sort()
      .limitFields()
      .search()
      .strictFilter('agency', req.currentUser!.agency);

    resourceCount = await countTotalFeatures._query.countDocuments();
    /************** GET RESOURCE TOTAL COUNT END **************/

    let query: DocumentQuery<Document[], Document> = Territory.find();

    if (!accessRoles.includes(role)) {
      query = query.where('agency').equals(req.currentUser!.agency);
    }

    const territoryFeatures = new ApiFeatures(query, req.query)
      .filter()
      .sort()
      .limitFields()
      .paginate(resourceCount.toString())
      .search();

    const territories = await territoryFeatures._query.populate([
      {
        path: 'createdBy',
        select: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'role', 'status'],
      },
      {
        path: 'area',
        select: ['code', 'description', 'status'],
      },
      {
        path: 'agency',
        select: ['code', 'description', 'status'],
      },
    ]);

    const response = {
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        results: territories.length,
        total: resourceCount,
        territories,
      },
    };

    res.send(response);
  }
);

export { router as getAllTerritoriesRouter };
```

I have updated mongoose and @types/mongoose to the latest and now I am getting the below error at line number 23.

[image]

I have been struggling with this for a while and can someone help me with this please??

Cheers